# How to do Number format in C#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

Given number is `282100`. I want to display above number like `282.100,00`
I am using

```
String.Format("{0:n}", number)
```

but I'm getting result like this `282,100.00`.
expected=`282.100,00`.
Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: Sounds like a culture issue.  Have you checked what culture your program is using?

Comment: Another way to handle it would be to do something like `String.Format("{0:###,###.##}", number);` although I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Use a culture that uses your desired delimiters, for example, de-DE: `String.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"), "{0:n}", 282100)`

Comment: current culture en-GB, that format is Norwegian.

Comment: Then that would be `"nn-NO"` or `"nb-NO"`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy thanks your solution is working.String.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"), "{0:n}", 282100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current culture does not format the number the way you want, you have a couple of options (at least):

- Use a known `CultureInfo` that does format the number the way you want
- Create a custom `NumberFormatInfo` that uses the format you want

In general, I'd say the first option is better. After all, if you have a need to format the number in a specific way, chances are it's because you are doing it for some specific culture. So the best way in that case is to just get the correct `CultureInfo` object (i.e. by using `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()`) and use that as the `IFormatProvider` for the formatting.

If for some reason it's not always clear which specific CultureInfo object to get, then you can do it the second way. For example:

```
decimal number = 282100;
NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo =
    (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
string text = string.Format(numberFormatInfo, "{0:n}", number);
```

This particular example allows you to start with a known formatter and then modify it per your specific needs.

Finally, if you believe your current culture should be formatting the number the way you want but it isn't doing that, then it is best to figure out why it's not doing that, rather than overriding the current culture. Usually, you *want* to use the default formatting for any text displayed to the user or received from the user, so that the program works correctly regardless of culture.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own number format and use that to get desired results. Something like this:

```
NumberFormatInfo customFormat = new NumberFormatInfo(); ;
customFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
customFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
customFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[1]{3};

decimal someNumber = 123456789.123m;
string number = someNumber.ToString("N",customFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the format by providing a new IFormatProvider:

```
var num = 282100;   

// Output using a custom formatter:
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N", 
    new NumberFormatInfo{ NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", NumberGroupSeparator = "."}));

// Or if you want to save the formatted string:
var str = String.Format(new NumberFormatInfo {NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", 
    NumberGroupSeparator = "."}, "{0:N}", num);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```